# CSS select odd/even class but under different parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Say the HTML mockup as follow:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="target">text in even</div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="target">text in odd</div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="target">text in even</div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="target">text in odd</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I test in jQuery that we can use jQuery's even/odd() method to select the intended class like the following:

```
> $(".target:even()")
> $(".target:odd()")
```

But is there a simple way in CSS? Please notice these .target classes have different parent and nth-child() and nth-of-type() does not work (please correct me if I am wrong).

Update: I tried also the following but didn't work for me.

```
.parent:nth-of-type(2n) target { }
.parent:nth-of-type(2n+1) target { }
```

Thank you!

Comment: `.parent:nth-child(even) .target`?

Comment: @haim770 I think I might have a syntax error, let me try again...

Comment: In jQuery you wouldn't use parenthesis in `$(".target:even()")` or `$(".target:odd()")`. Also, in your CSS example, `.parent:nth-of-type(2n) target { }` you missed the `.` in front of `target`.

Comment: @DylanHsiao haims solution should work, and it does in this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/virhonestum/o65prbdv/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `nth-child(odd) and nth-child(even)` for this

```css
.parent:nth-child(even) .target{
color:green;
}

.parent:nth-child(odd) .target{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="target">text in odd</div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="target">text in even</div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="target">text in odd</div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="target">text in even</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**P.S** you missed `.` in target while using nth-of-type

```css
.parent:nth-of-type(2n)  .target{
color:green;
}

.parent:nth-of-type(2n+1)  .target{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="target">text in odd</div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="target">text in even</div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="target">text in odd</div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="target">text in even</div>
    </div>
</div>
```